# knockout cross view model

Tags: javascript, cordova, knockout.js

```
var barcodeNum = ko.observable("");

VelocityMeetings.scan = function (params) {

var errorMessage = ko.observable("");

var viewModel = {
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    scannumber: ko.observable(""),
    errorVisible: ko.computed(function () {
        return errorMessage().length != 0;
    }),
    scanBarcode: function () {
        //Capture image with device and process into barcode
        capturePhoto();

        this.scannumber(barcodeNum());
        //this.errorMessage(errMessage);
    },
};


return viewModel;
};
```

I have the barcodeNum variable created outside of the view model, to try and pass data back into the scannumber variable.  How do I access a variable defined inside of a view model?

The goal is to use the javascript Worker I have, to update the scannumber which will update my app accordingly, but I can't get it to function properly.

```
function receiveMessage(e) {
    barcodeNum("Test function");
}

var DecodeWorker = new Worker("js/BarcodeScanner.js");
DecodeWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
```

The goal is something along the lines of this

```
VelocityMeetings.scan.viewModel.scannumber(barcodeNum());
```

but this isnt working properly

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself working with separate view models that have to communicate with each other, consider using [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox).  You can make the communication one-way or two-way if you want.  In your case, I think a one-way communication will be enough.

```
var barcodeNum = ko.observable('').publishOn('barcodeNum');

var viewModel = {
    scannumber: ko.observable().subscribeTo('barcodeNum'),
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue my self

```
scannumber: ko.observable(""),
```

scannumber can be defined as ko.computed with the return value being barcodeNum(), that will make any change made to barcodeNum also made to scannumber()

here is my computed

```
 scannumber: ko.computed(function () { return barcodeNum(); },this),
```